# Handle Timeout in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlsession, alamofire-request

I want to handle timeout error with Alamofire as follow.

1. User initiate request with button press
2. If timeout occurs then it will display message with custom view with 2 buttons (cancel & retry)
3. if user presses retry_button the request should retry

I already made a general class for Alamofire configuration & also add `Interceptor Protocol`

But I think request will retry automatically without user interaction.

My Code is as follow:

```
let config = Session.default.session.configuration
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1 

public func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {

       //TODO: How to retry request when retry_button press in custom view
    }
```

Thank you for your valuable time to at least read my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Make the request with a different configuration which does not have a retrier (not having a retrier means that the `retry` method will not get called). Then retry the request whenever the user clicks on the Retry button.

```
var customSessionManager = SessionManager()
customSessionManager.retrier = nil
customSessionManager.request( ... ) {
    // request is being made with no retrier. Hence retry method will not be called.
}
```

### Solution 2

When making this network request, remove [`.validate()`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-validation) from the `Alamofire` request. This way, `Alamofire` will not validate whether the response had an unacceptable status code. The `retry` method will not get called, and we can write the logic to retry the request whenever the user presses the Retry button.

### Solution 3

*(I haven't tested this method at the time of writing this answer.)*

If there is really no way to go with Solution 1 or Solution 2, you could try recursively calling the `retry` method, while waiting for the user to click on the Cancel or Retry button. When the user clicks on the Cancel or Retry button, set a property in a SingletonClass, and use the value of that same property in the retry method to determine whether that request should be retried or cancelled.

```
SingletonClass.retryRequest = false // initial default value
SingletonClass.cancelRequest = false // initial default value
```

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonWasPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    SingletonClass.cancelRequest = true
}

@IBAction func retryButtonWasPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    SingletonClass.retryRequest = true
}
```

```
public func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
    if SingletonClass.retryRequest && !SingletonClass.cancelRequest {
        // This means the user clicked on the Retry button.
        SingletonClass.retryRequest = false // reset the value back to false
        completion(.retry)
    } else if !SingletonClass.retryRequest && SingletonClass.cancelRequest {
        // This means the user clicked on the Cancel button.
        SingletonClass.cancelRequest = false
        completion(.doNotRetry)
    } else {
        // Recursively call the retry method till the user clicks on either the Cancel or Retry button.
        retry(request, for session, dueTo error, completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check your all possible way & let you know.